# Uploading Images on Google Drive from IOS Application

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am working with an IOS application ,in which I have to upload images on Google Drive .I am able to upload the images on `GDrive`,but first I want to create folder and then upload the selected images in that folder.
How could I create that album folder and then insert that images in that folder.
Please help I searched everywhere,but not getting the solution.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Warning, none of the code below was not typed in any IDE. It is just to get you moving in the right direction :)

First, create the empty folder with something like this:

```
GTLDriveFile *folderObj = [GTLDriveFile object];
folderObj.title = folderName;
folderObj.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folderObj uploadParameters:nil];
```

Then, when you are inserting the file, you will want to add the ID of this new folder to its parent references using something similar to:

```
GTLDriveParentReference *parentRef = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
parentRef.identifier = theFoldersId;
fileObj.parents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:parentRef];
```